# Calculating number of possibilities of arranging years with a distance in between

Tags: probability

I am trying to find a formula for the number of possibilities I can arrange a timeframe in when there has to be a gap in between the years.

**The problem is as follows:** I have a period of 10 years of income data. I need to calculate the difference between two periods with at least two years in between those periods. An example for 5 years of data (2014-2018):

2 years in between: 2014-2017, 2015-2018

3 years in between: 2014-2018

so 3 possibilities.

I know that for 9 years of data there should be 22 possibilities. Which formula can I use to calculate the number of possibilities?